# Using emit with Kotlin StateFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, android-livedata, kotlin-coroutines

Until now I was using `Flow` and mapping it to `LiveData` like below -

The `MyService` looks like this -

```
override fun provideData(action: MyAction) = flow {
   emit(MyResult.Loading)
   emit(dataRepository.getNewData())
}
```

The `ViewModel` looks like this -

```
fun getData() = myService.provideData(MyAction.GetData).map {
                
}.asLiveData(Dispatchers.Default + viewModelScope.coroutineContext)
```

I want to move to `StateFlow`. How can I use `emit` function with `StateFlow` like I used it with `Flow`.

Comment: You...can't, really.  `StateFlow` isn't just a different version of `Flow` that you can "move to," it's a tool to use with a specific kind of flow logic.  What you do with a `StateFlow` is you set its current value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can write your flow as before, but replace `.asLiveData(scope)` with `.stateIn(scope, SharingStarted.Eagerly, null)` to get an instance of `StateFlow` running in the corresponding scope with a similar behavior that you were getting with `LiveData` before — sharing is started immediately and the initial value is `null` (just like with `LiveData`).

You can read here for more details and explanation of all `stateIn` operator parameters here https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines.flow/state-in.html